# Changing the font size of subscripts for a certain text font size

Tags: math-mode, formatting, subscripts

I want to make my subscripts smaller, but only if the text font is in `\scriptsize`. Is there a way to do this? All proposed solutions to make subscripts smaller that I could find so far didn't change anything at all unfortunately.

Here is my current preamble as well as some sample equations:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, top = 0.8cm, left = 1cm, right = 1cm, bottom = 0.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{0pt}}
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
       {\scriptsize 
       \begin{align*}
            F_S &= \text{Schraubenkraft}\\
            F_P &= \text{Plattenkraft}\\
            F_V &= \text{Vorspannkraft}\\
            f_S &= \text{Verkürzung der Schraube}\\
            f_P &= \text{Verkürzung der Platten}\\
        \end{align*}}
\end{document}
```

It currently looks like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}%scalable cm
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, top = 0.8cm, left = 1cm, right = 1cm, bottom = 0.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{0pt}}
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\DeclareMathSizes
   {8}% Specification of math fonts for this size of surrounding text
   {8}% size of \displaystyle and \textstyle 
   {2}% size of \scriptstyle
   {1}% size of \scriptscriptstyle


\begin{document}
       {\scriptsize  
       \begin{align*}
            F_S &= \text{Schraubenkraft}\\
            F_P &= \text{Plattenkraft}\\
            F_V &= \text{Vorspannkraft}\\
            f_S &= \text{Verkürzung der Schraube}\\
            f_P &= \text{Verkürzung der Platten}\\
        \end{align*}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, the \Requirepackage{fix-cm} did the trick! May I ask what the two latter parameters do exactly? I know that I can change the size by changing both of them, but what does each one of them do?

Comment: @Skydiver added commented version

Comment: What would be the values to change \footnotesize as well?

Comment: do what I did use `\makeatletter\footnotesize\show\f@size` and see what size it says:-)

Comment: @Skydiver (but size12.clo has `\newcommand\footnotesize{\@setfontsize\footnotesize\@xpt\@xiipt` so footnotesize is 10pt so you want the first two arguments to be 10